# Not able to get type of value in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Not able to get type of value in robot framework. I got TypeError needs an argument. I tried multiple ways to sort this issue but no luck.

```
TC_005_Validate that Subscribing with Empty Mandatory fields should Failed
    [Documentation]  User need to check that the Invalid data is not allowed
    ${body}=  create dictionary  resource={"name":'',"display_id":'', "ont_id":'', "ont_name":''}  action=${ADD}
    ${response}=  HTTP_API  ${body}  ${type_subscriber}
    log to console   The status Code is: ${response.status_code}
    log to console  The Response Body is: ${response.json()}
    ${StatusCode}=  convert to string  ${response.status_code}
    should be equal  ${StatusCode}  500
    ${errrespose1}=  Fetch ErrCode  ${response}
    ${err1}=  convert to string  ${errrespose1}
    should be equal  ${err1}  -1
    ${messageResponse}=  Fetch message  ${response}
    ${message1}=  convert to string   ${messageResponse}
    log to console  The message is : ${message1}
    ${type1}=    Evaluate    type($message1)
    log to console    The type1:    ${type1}
    ${type2}=    Evaluate    type($Mandatorymsg)
    log to console    The type2:    ${type2}
    sleep  2s
    should be equal as strings   ${message1}   ${Mandatorymsg}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ WARN ] Keyword 'RequestsLibrary.Post Request' is deprecated. Please use `POST On Session` instead.
TC_005_Validate that Subscribing with Empty Mandatory fields shoul... C:\Users\Amit.Bhalla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1043: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '10.157.255.51'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
.The status Code is: 500
.The Response Body is: {'errCode': -1, 'message': 'Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber '}
[ WARN ] Keyword 'RequestsLibrary.To Json' is deprecated. Please use ${resp.json()} instead. Have a look at the improved HTML output as pretty printing replacement.
TC_005_Validate that Subscribing with Empty Mandatory fields shoul... {'errCode': -1, 'message': 'Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber '}
-1
-1
[ WARN ] Keyword 'RequestsLibrary.To Json' is deprecated. Please use ${resp.json()} instead. Have a look at the improved HTML output as pretty printing replacement.
TC_005_Validate that Subscribing with Empty Mandatory fields shoul... {'errCode': -1, 'message': 'Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber '}
**..The message is : Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber**
TC_005_Validate that Subscribing with Empty Mandatory fields shoul... | FAIL |
**TypeError: unbound method str.lower() needs an argument**
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? At which step it has failed? Better show the error in robot log.xml

Comment: Hi , I am trying to compare message in Json to hard code value ....both are strings but still it is failing.

Comment: There are warnings telling you that you're using deprecated features. Have you tried taking the advice presented in the errors and switched your code to the supported functions? It might not make a different but you should do it anyway.

Comment: It appears that the REST endpoint you're calling requires a mandatory field that you aren't providing. Have you checked the documentation for the endpoint to make sure you're calling it properly?